# Chocolatey package will not install rabbitmq and erlang as dependencies

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, chocolatey

I have created a nuget package (nupkg) and stored it in a gitlab package registry.

The .nuspec file used to create the package contains:

1. Reference to a directory containing a Windows service .msi installer (file tag). The .msi is included in the package.
2. Reference to a couple of dependencies which are to be downloaded from the chocolatey repository.

```
 <dependencies>
   <dependency id="erlang" version="26.2.1" />
   <dependency id="rabbitmq" version="3.12.10" />
 </dependencies>
```

When I call 'choc install' in powershell  on my local machine the msi is downloaded and installed but the two dependency tags are completely ignored.
There are no errors raised in powershell or in the chocolatey logs.

I can install both erlang and rabbitmq using the 'choco install' command in powershell, but they will not install as a dependency in a nuget package.

I have tried this on a clean VM, but still does not work.

When I use the -v option, I get the following:

```
[NuGet] Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
```

Can anyone help?
Many thanks.

Comment: > two dependency tags 

What do you mean by this? A Chocolatey package doesn't have 'dependency tags'. It does have `<dependecies>` specified in the `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Also see the docs - https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/package-dependencies

Comment: Yes, the dependencies are in specified the .nuspec file e.g.  
   <dependencies>
   <dependency id="erlang" version="26.2.1" />
   <dependency id="rabbitmq" version="3.12.10" />
    </dependencies>
I assume when installing the package from gitlab, chocolatey will first install the 2 dependicies, but it ignores them completely.

Comment: It will only ignore dependencies if they are already installed at a version at least that of which you specified, or if it cannot find them. If there is anything else then the best thing to do is raise an issue at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues because info can be gathered there.